# How do I fill the transparent areas of this vector in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a vector that I downloaded from a stock image site. If you look at the vector you will see that it has some transparent specs within the black and red areas. How do I get rid of the transparent areas so that the black and red areas are totally solid? The transparent "Family Reunion" is fine and needs to stay. I just want to get rid of the little specs.

[image: The vector I'm trying to edit]

I should also mention that the vector isn't organized in a user friendly manner. It's just a bunch of paths and compound paths encapsulated by a group. See screenshot from layers panel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There may be an automated method, but a manual approach isn't particularly difficult. Select for example, the lower black "gear" segment. Ensure that you are selecting only the stroke or path and copy it to a holding or temporary layer by pasting in place. Turn of the visibility for that layer to ensure you don't select it again by mistake. Delete everything remaining in that area, which will include the transparent sections you wish removed. Un-hide the previous segment, fill with black. Repeat for the other sections.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the vector with the transparent areas you want to fill
then click on the letter K on keyborad (live paint tool) the you should be able 
to fill any area you need :) 
update me with the result.
goodluck

Comment: I tried that but there are hundreds of those transparent little specs. That would take me a while and would be my last resort.

Comment: Try the "Shape Builder Tool" click on Shift+M

Comment: So you can merge the tiny shapes and it would make it easier to fill, you have to select all then use the Shape Builder Tool